# How to show unicode string (&#x) in TextView?

Tags: android, unicode

there are some strings like &#x6211;&#x7684; ("我的" in Chinese) in database, but I don't know how to display them in a TextView. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Put `\u` in front of the code: `\u6211`

Comment: How can I do that? Use regular expression to replace &#x to \u?

Comment: While using regular expressions in replacemens, you need to use \\ for \, since it's a special character (escape char). By the way, `String.replace()` uses regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey maybe you can try with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textFromDatabse));
```